# Obtain Facebook Events using restfb

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I need to obtain all public events from my fb page.
It's not possible using an App access token anymore: "Requires a valid Page or User access token with basic permissions." - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

I don't want to put my User credentials into my Application.

Current code:

```java
FacebookClient.AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.LATEST).obtainAppAccessToken(facebookProperties.getAppId(), facebookProperties.getAppSecret());
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getAccessToken(), Version.LATEST);
Date now = new Date();

Connection<com.restfb.types.Event> eventConnection = facebookClient.fetchConnection(facebookProperties.getPageId() + "/events", com.restfb.types.Event.class, Parameter.with("fields", "name,start_time"));
List<Event> events = eventConnection.getData().stream().filter(facebookEvent -> now.compareTo(Optional.ofNullable(facebookEvent.getEndTime()).orElse(facebookEvent.getStartTime())) <= 0).map(facebookEvent -> Event.fromFacebookEvent(facebookEvent)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

A dirty Workaround would be creating a new fb account, adding it as a Page admin and provide its Credentials. Is there a better way to simply obtain the public Events?

Comment: that workaround is not allowed. there is no other way. you don´t put your user credentials anyway, you just authorize the app and get an access token. with that, you get a page token.

Comment: You do realize that right on top of that documentation page it says, _“This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.”_ …? You can use whatever kind of token you want, that’s not gonna change anything.